# Convert all sheets in hyperlink except the index page

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I am working on a small project but facing a little problem.

I have plenty of worksheets in my excel workbook and i want them to be accessed using the hyperlink.

For example, I have four sheets in my Excel workbook named as "Index List", "Sheet2", "Sheet3" and "Sheet 4" respectively. I want the list of all worksheets except the Index List on the index sheet and hyperlink with the respective sheet.

So far I have been successful in creating the hyperlinks but it creates a Index List sheet link also.

Here is my code:

```
Sub AddLinks()
        Dim wksLinks As Worksheet
        Dim wks As Worksheet
        Dim row As Integer
        Set wksLinks = Worksheets("Index List")
        wksLinks.UsedRange.Delete
        row = 1
        For Each wks In Worksheets
           ' Debug.Print wks.Name
            wks.Hyperlinks.Add wksLinks.Cells(row, 1), "", wks.Name & "!A1", , wks.Name
            row = row + 1
        Next wks
    End Sub
```

Kindly review it and help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional logic:

```
    For Each wks In Worksheets
       If Not wks.Name = "Index List" Then 
           wks.Hyperlinks.Add wksLinks.Cells(row, 1), "", wks.Name & "!A1", , wks.Name
           row = row + 1
       End If
    Next wks
```

To ignore multiple sheets, use a `Select` statement, instead (these are IMO easier to read than chained IF conditions:

```
    For Each wks In Worksheets
       Select Case LCase(wks.Name)
          Case "index list", "some other sheet", "etc."
              'Do nothing, but print some debug info
              Debug.Print "Skpping " & wks.Name
          Case Else
               'Add the hyperlink to this sheet
               wks.Hyperlinks.Add wksLinks.Cells(row, 1), "", wks.Name & "!A1", , wks.Name
               row = row + 1
       End Select
    Next wks
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. But if i want to ignore multiple sheets what will need to be changed?

Comment: I'd use a `Select` statement instead, see revision.

Comment: Thanks but it isnt ignoring the defined sheets....

Comment: Make sure the `Case` statement is all lower-case, so if a sheet is named "Index List" put it in `Case "index list", "etc."`

Comment: thanks David, its working now but can you please tell me the reason behind setting the sheets name into lower case.

Comment: The reason I do this is because `Select Case LCase(wks.Name)` converts the sheet name to lower-case, this is because the Select statement is case-sensitive, but worksheet names are not, so it's to avoid errors if you don't have the right lower/upper case.

Comment: Alternatively, you would have to do `Case "Index List", "Index list", "index List", "INDEX LIST", "InDeX LiSt", ...` to cover all possible permutations of upper/lower/camel-case.  Since a worksheet name is not case sensitive, most developers will convert such strings to either UPPER or lower case.

Comment: Thanks David for your help. It really solved my problem